# Constructing pandas DF with model trained categorical variable

Tags: pandas, categorical-data, lightgbm

I've trained a lightGBM model on a dataset X where X has a categorical (in the pandas sense) variable. This model trains fine and when I predict using it all looks good - I can even change the value of the categorical variable in a given row and the correct change happens in the output.

However, when I try to programmatically create a dataframe to predict on using the following code:

```
probs = model.predict_proba(df)
event = random.choices(model.classes_, weights=probs)
df['next_event'] = pd.Categorical(event, categories=next_event_categories)
```

I get the wrong output. Even if I hard-code the `event` variable to different categories it always comes out with the same output. `next_event_categories` is `X_train.next_event.cat.categories` so should be the exact categories needed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to randomly choose from the labels provided from the model? Even so you can just use: ```df['next_event'] = event```

Comment: @MichaelHiggins We can ignore how event is chosen, think you'd have this issue regardless. Unfortunately that doesn't work because that col in the df needs to be of dtype category of the same form as the training data whereas event is object. If I were to then predict on df using model2 (which has next_event categorical as a training var), it will treat it as NaN.

Comment: I don't think probs has the right data structure, its a list of lists... I think you want ```event = random.choices(model.classes_, weights=[p[1] for p in probs])```

Comment: You're right, I'd changed this to probs[0], but regardless, that bit is working fine. It's the category encoding that I can't get working, always says the categories between the train and valid sets are different - by valid set it means the df I'm predicting on